# Replacing hash through location.replace considered harmful?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

In an application that I encounter hash replacement is done through:

```
var loc = window.location + ''
loc = loc.substr(0, loc.indexOf('#'))
loc += '#somehash'
location.replace(loc)
```

instead of:

```
location.hash = '#somehash'
```

Now DOMinator Pro gives a 'URL Redirection JSExecution' warning about this as we call `location.replace` with data that comes from window.location. What I'm wondering now is whether this is a real threat, as I can't think of a way an attacker can abuse this to perform a URL redirect exploit.

Is this a real attack vector, or a false positive?

Comment: If the attacker can some how influence the value of `window.location`, then you could have a problem.

Comment: Well, yeah, but is there any way the attacker can do that without an extra XSS?

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna say this is a false positive attack vector according to [this article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_DOM-based_Cross_site_scripting_%28OTG-CLIENT-001%29), the only known way to inject the website is throught adding the #maliciouscode into your URL bar, however your function ignores the # fragments, so no code is really pasted in the website.

Answer (score 1):

There is an attack vector, though I cannot think of a way it cannot be used in your case.

However, the suggested code is definitely clearer, less error-prone, and therefore safer.

I could contrive an example attack if you had used the `slice` method instead of `substr`. Should make no difference, should it? Then try it out with the location `http://example.com` (no trailing slash). If you'd execute the script with

```
loc = loc.slice(0, loc.indexOf('#'));
```

then you'll end up at `http://example.co#somehash`, which might be registered by the attacker.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answers that this is probably a false positive.  Still, it's certainly easy to make mistakes with such code, as Bergi's `slice` example shows.

In [modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#Browser_compatibility), this code could be more cleanly written as:

```js
var loc = new URL("#somehash", location);
location.replace(loc);
```

This avoids any possibility of subtly messing up the URL manipulation.